# Volume using triple integrals is $0$ while using rectangular coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, surface-integrals

I need to find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces $ +  − 1 = 0$ , $ = 1$ and
$^2 + ^2 = 4$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, when I use the triple integral:
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{0}\int_{1}^{1-x}dz~dy~dx$$, I get the answer $0$. Therefore, I have to find the volume using another integral:
$$2\int_{-2}^{0}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{0}\int_{1}^{1-x}dz~dy~dx$$ which gives me the answer $\frac{16}{3}$. (I am not sure this is correct.)

Am I taking the right limits for the integrals?

Comment: Did you draw the figure? For example, when $x\in[0,2]$, then $1>1-x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing the surfaces of Cartesian equation:

$$
z = 1,
\quad \quad \quad \quad
z = 1 - x,
\quad \quad \quad \quad
x^2 + y^2 = 4
$$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

it follows that the volume of the enclosed region of space is equal to:

$$
V = 2\cdot\iiint\limits_{\{x<0,\,1<z<1-x,\,x^2+y^2<4\}} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z = 2\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \text{d}\theta \int_0^2 \rho\,\text{d}\rho \int_1^{1-\rho\cos\theta} 1\,\text{d}z = \boxed{\frac{32}{3}}
$$

Answer (score 4):

As I wrote in comment it's better to separate figure with respect to $z=1-x$ and $z=1$ interdependence, thanks for the great drawing from TeM, we have
$$\int\limits_{-2}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int\limits_{1-x}^{1}dzdxdy+\int\limits_{-2}^{2}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{0}\int\limits_{1}^{1-x}dzdxdy = \frac{16}{3}+\frac{16}{3}= \frac{32}{3}$$